# javascript: Referring to a variable in 'same' an object literal

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following bit of javascript, actually its in angular but its the same..

I am trying to set expertUri variable by concating the previous variable but i can't get it to work. I tried "this" ... but still no luck.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('testme')
    .constant('config', {
        standardUri: 'http://localhost/setup',
        expertUri : standardUri+ '/expert'  // THIS FAILS
});
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: You can't do this because you're writing it as an _Object literal_, so it doesn't really exist until after the literal has ended.

Answer (score 0):

At the time you try to access standardUri it hasn't been defined yet. Even if it was, you wouldn't be able to access it this way, since it's an object property, and not a variable.

This should work:

```
'use strict';

var standardUri = 'http://localhost/setup';
angular.module('testme')
    .constant('config', {
        standardUri: standardUri,
        expertUri : standardUri+ '/expert'
});
```

Comment: but thats creating standardURI outside of the angular  module

Comment: I've assumed that this snippet is a body of a self-invoking function. I don't see any disadvantages in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to "make this work" without introducing new variables is to have *expertUri* as a *getter*

```
{
    standardUri: 'http://localhost/setup',
    get expertUri () {return this.standardUri + '/expert';}
}
```

This means that every time you try to access the property *expertUri*, you're actually invoking a *function* where `this` will permit you to access the *Object*.

Comment: getters/setters are available since IE9. Which is not very bad, but also not very good.

Comment: I was about to ask about the get keyboard, first time I saw it :-) IE8 would fail then? Is there an alternative to make it backward compatible?

Comment: Would this be backward compatible?
        expertUri : function()  {return this.standardUri + '/expert';},

Comment: but then I have to call it via expertUri() passing the brackets

Comment: No there is no way to make this backward-compatible. I doubt that putting a function there would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an anonymous function and invoke it immediately to create the object, this hides the variable but it feels like a hammer to crack a nut...

```
angular.module('testme')
.constant('config', 
(function() {
  var stdUri = 'http://localhost/setup';
  return {
    standardUri: stdUri,
    expertUri : stdUri+ '/expert'
    };
  }
}())
);
```